# Numkey on the right of DELL laptop

Tags: keyboard

The Numkeys on my Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) not working.  Please help me get it reactivated.

---

When I run `xev` I get the following when I press the key:

```
MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x15e, subw 0x0, time 6517481, (66,7), root:(106,89),
    state 0x10, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x15e, subw 0x0, time 6517489, (66,3), root:(106,85),
    state 0x10, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
```

Comment: @Abdul I have copied your post into your question, when including the output of commands, etc. please add them as edits to your question and not as individual comments.

Comment: What model of Dell laptop do you have?  Does it have a separate 10-keypad on the right side of the keyboard, or is the keypad built into the keys themselves like on the `uiopjkl;m,./` keys?  You might want to see:  https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln285209/dell-latitude-e6400-e6410-and-e6500-keyboard-guide?lang=en if it is built into the keys themselves.

Comment: Yes,it is Dell Inspiron 15 500 series.It has got a separate number keypad on the right.

Comment: Is the NumLock button not working then?  Does it work before you enter Ubuntu if you maybe boot to a root prompt under advanced safe boot from GRUB?  Have you checked the BIOS for any NumLock settings?  Also, `xev` may not work if you are running the GNOME desktop with Wayland enabled since `xev` is `xev - print contents of X events`